# Communication between Django applications hosted in different servers

Tags: django

I have a Django project hosted in a server and it wants to interact with another django application hosted in another server. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you specify what exaclty you want to communicate?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what exactly you want to communicate. But irrespective of specific technology, [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is one of the best practices when it comes to communication between applications.

There are numerous apps developed to help RESTful implementation in Django. You can try [RestifyDjango](http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/wiki/RestifyDjango) or [Django REST framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework)